# Hypersurface four-vector, or a familly of four 3-forms?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, integration, vector-fields

While reading my old personal notes on forms in relativity, I got confused about some aspects of the mathematical formalism (integration on tensors and p-forms).  The energy-momentum flux across some hypersurface $\Sigma$ in spacetime is defined as this:
$$\int_{\Sigma} T^{ab} \, d\sigma_b, \tag{1}$$
where $d\sigma_b$ are the *covariant* components of the hypersurface normal.  Lets work in special relativity with cartesian coordinates, for simplicity.  I'm using $c = 1$ and metric signature $\eta = (1, -1, -1, -1)$.  Usually:
\begin{align}
d\sigma_0 &= d^3 x = dx \, dy \, dz, \tag{2a} \\
d\sigma_1 &= dt \, dS_x = dt \, dy \, dz, \tag{2b} \\
d\sigma_2 &= dt \, dS_y = dt \, dz \, dx, \tag{2c}\\
d\sigma_3 &= dt \, dS_z = dt \, dx \, dy. \tag{2d}
\end{align}
These infinitesimal elements could be interpreted as the *covariant components* of a four-vector in spacetime (maybe I'm doing a mistake here!).

Now, we could introduce a familly of four 3-forms (fully antisymetric rank 3 tensors):
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
d\boldsymbol{\sigma}_a = \frac{1}{3!} \, \varepsilon_{abcd} \, \mathbf{d}x^b \wedge \mathbf{d}x^c \wedge \mathbf{d}x^d \equiv \varepsilon_{abcd} \, \mathbf{d}x^b \otimes \mathbf{d}x^c \otimes \mathbf{d}x^d,
\end{equation}
where $\varepsilon_{abcd}$ is the totally antisymetric permutation Levi-Civita symbol and $\varepsilon_{0123} \equiv 1$.  Explicitely, this expression gives **four 3-forms** (or tensors):
\begin{align}
d\boldsymbol{\sigma}_0 &= +\: \mathbf{d}x \wedge \mathbf{d}y \wedge \mathbf{d}z, \tag{4a} \\
d\boldsymbol{\sigma}_1 &= -\, \mathbf{d}t \wedge \mathbf{d}y \wedge \mathbf{d}z, \tag{4b} \\
d\boldsymbol{\sigma}_2 &= -\, \mathbf{d}t \wedge \mathbf{d}z \wedge \mathbf{d}x, \tag{4c} \\
d\boldsymbol{\sigma}_3 &= -\, \mathbf{d}t \wedge \mathbf{d}x \wedge \mathbf{d}y, \tag{4d}
\end{align}
which are very similar to components (2).

So my question is what actually is the **hypersurface normal**?  A *four-vector* of infinitesimal covariant components $d\sigma_a$, or a set of *four 3-forms* $d\boldsymbol{\sigma}_a$ (i.e antisymetric co-tensors)?

Also, are the 3-forms (3)-(4) a *Hodge dual* of something else?

Why am I confused with this??

Comment: Strictly speaking 1-forms and vectors live in different spaces.  In SR they may not look much different.  In GR, based on diff geom, each point of a manifold has a tangent space T(M,p) where local tangent vectors live, and a dual tangent space T*(M,p).   There is a one to one correspondence between an N-1 form and N vectors when dim(M) = N and Hodge does help make that mapping.

Comment: @ggcg, I agree.  I already knew that the vectors and forms are living in different spaces ($\mathscr{E}$ and $\mathscr{E}^{*}$), and that they be mapped one into another with the help of the metric.  However, I'm still confused about the normal to an hypersurface in 4D spacetime and how the integration is defined.